# How to get popup when url status success in angular js

Tags: angularjs, popup

I am doing an event scheduler app using angular js. In calendar when i am clicking  the event i am sent the event id to back end to getting event details.Here how to get the pop up on my calendar when the url status is true.

My code is:

```
$scope.alertOnEventClick = function( date, jsEvent, view){
    var event_id=date.id;
    $http.post("Youin-api/v2/business/event_information",{"event_id":event_id}).then(function(response) {
    if(response.error="true")
    {
      $scope.eventInformation= response;
    }
    }); 
    };
```

My bootstrap model pop up is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AddUsers" ng-model="eventInformation" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog " style="top:80px;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">User Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><form role="form" ng-submit="AddUsers(addusers)">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">User Type</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="user_type" ng-model="addusers.user_type" value="{{addusers.user_type}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Created By</label>
      <input ty{{addusers.user_type}}pe="text" class="form-control"   id="created_by" ng-model="addusers.created_by" value="">
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
         </form></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You want to display the popup when the `$http` call is completed?

Comment: how can i do it?.how to call my pop up id in angular js??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually trigger modal to show from javascript. Use this.

```
$('#AddUsers').modal('show')
```

Note: You have to add `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` to use this functionality.

You can view the complete modal api options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript).

Comment: Glad it helped. and Including jquery is necessary for bootstrap. its not for just selecting the id. It is recommended by `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you want to open the modal based on your condition you can achieve the same using following:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById("AddUsers")).modal();
```